# gdm3 on debian wheezy not remembering users after reboot

Tags: user, debian-wheezy, gdm

When logging on and off from gnome/gdm3, the last user is displayed as expected. As soon as I reboot the machine (or restart dbus and gdm3) the last user list is empty again.
ck-history --last shows all previous users.

Any hints what might go wrong?

Comment: Is it supposed to show the last user after a reboot?

Comment: I see it on another machine correctly...